# Swiftmailer hide Users email from MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, email

I need to design a email messaging form for a website

I should allow different USERS to contact each other via email

After a USER uses the form to send an email to another USER it should send the email but hide the email address, so for example the email header will be

```
      Charles via poster.1033316576.7OEWA@users.yoursite.com
      to:    John@gmail.com
      date:  Tue, Dec 24, 2013 at 4:46 PM
      subject:   "Recent review of "Wolf of Wall Street"
      mailed-by:     users.yoursite.com

      Hey John

      I read your review of Wolf of Wall St. I thought you anaylsis was very good.

      etc...
```

USERS can reply to the email, but the email address will always be hidden.

Can you suggest a way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a commercial component

- Sendgrid's: [Inbound Parse Webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html)
- Mandrill's [Inbound Email Processing Overview](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-overview)

That would mean, that all the replies will go to them, and they will process it, and respond to your `callback URL` the parsed reply.

You need to make sure, that each email you send out, has some identification like: Sendgrid header params, or `X-Headers` setup that will identity your context eg: user id, topic id. As you will need this to identify who replied and on what context.

You could setup a full server doing all this on your own, but that would mean you would also need to do the system maintenance and email parsing, so I would go with solutions like Sendgrid or Mandrill. I prefer Sendgrid.

Comment: The unique USER ID poster.1033316576.7OEWA@users.yoursite.com
of the USER needs to be generated dynamically when a USER posts a new review on the site.  
If I use a 3rd party email service, I will have to log in and update the Inbound Routes as soon as a new unique ID is posted.  That's not possible.                                                                        I am looking for a script that will do this on my own server.

Comment: You understood this wrong, you don't have to update on every change. Read it further.